# How to optimise the query in PostgreSQL for function ST_Difference?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

- **PostgreSQL**

I executed below query for 4 million of geometry polygon in PostgreSQL. It took unlimited time which I need to stop the execution after 2 hour.

```
 SELECT 
      c.id, 
     c.classification,
    ST_Difference(b.geom, c.geom)
    FROM 
      public."city" c,
    public.b
    where 
    c.classificationin ('Class I','Sub Metro City','Class II','Metro City','Class III','Mega City');
```

- **QGIS**

The same layer I used in **QGIS** using **Difference** in **Vector >> Geoprocessing Tools** and it took hardly 3 minutes to clip the region.

Please help me out

> **how can i optimize the query in PostgreSQL ?**

Comment: Check first that both tables have spatial index. Then you could have a try by adding AND b.geom && c.geom to your SQL.

Comment: I would even extend the where clause with st_intersects(b.geom, c.geom), too, not to get empty geometry in the result, && works on the minimal boundary rectangle (MBR). Do you have an index on c.classification?

Comment: @Zoltan i also tried with the St_intersects, its takes the same time

Comment: @user30184 yes it does have spatial index on both the table

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN QUERY` show the query planner is doing? Also, make sure the code you are really running is what is above - fix the typos.

Comment: I believe that the problem with the original query is that it is computing difference for every possible a-b pair and the product of (4 million * x) is huge. There must be a way to put more sense to the query and I believed that &&, or Intersects would be the way. Unfortunately it does not seem to be. How many features you have in a and in b? I do not quite understand what kind of data you have, could you add an image showing a few features from a and b?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the where clause in a sub query, so the selection is done first then the difference.

A similar problem can be found here

[PostGIS doesn't use spatial index with ST_Intersects](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130856/postgis-doesnt-use-spatial-index-with-st-intersects)