# Why is st_intersects faster than &&

Tags: postgis, carto, postgis-2.2

It's a table of points. ~1M records

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as value FROM alasarr_social_mv s; 
Output: 976270
```

It looks like st_intersects forces to use the spatial indexes but && doesn't.

### Sample using `ST_Intersects` (282ms)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as value
FROM alasarr_social_mv 
WHERE ST_Intersects(
  the_geom_webmercator, 
  ST_MakeEnvelope(-410961,4920492,-402305,4926887,3857)
)


Aggregate  (cost=34370.18..34370.19 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=282.715..282.715 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on alasarr_social_mv s  (cost=5572.17..34339.84 rows=60683 width=0) (actual time=21.574..240.195 rows=178010 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (the_geom_webmercator && '0103000020110F0000010000000500000000000000441519C1000000002BC5524100000000441519C1000000C069CB524100000000048E18C1000000C069CB524100000000048E18C1000000002BC5524100000000441519C1000000002BC55241'::geometry)
        Filter: _st_intersects(the_geom_webmercator, '0103000020110F0000010000000500000000000000441519C1000000002BC5524100000000441519C1000000C069CB524100000000048E18C1000000C069CB524100000000048E18C1000000002BC5524100000000441519C1000000002BC55241'::geometry)
        Heap Blocks: exact=4848
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on alasarr_social_mv_gix  (cost=0.00..5569.13 rows=182050 width=0) (actual time=20.836..20.836 rows=178010 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (the_geom_webmercator && '0103000020110F0000010000000500000000000000441519C1000000002BC5524100000000441519C1000000C069CB524100000000048E18C1000000C069CB524100000000048E18C1000000002BC5524100000000441519C1000000002BC55241'::geometry)
Planning time: 0.192 ms
Execution time: 282.758 ms
```

### Sample using `&&` (414ms)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as value
FROM alasarr_social_mv  
WHERE the_geom_webmercator && 
  ST_MakeEnvelope(-410961,4920492,-402305,4926887,3857)

Aggregate  (cost=22535.97..22535.97 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=414.314..414.314 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on alasarr_social_mv  (cost=0.00..22444.94 rows=182050 width=0) (actual time=0.017..378.427 rows=178010 loops=1)
        Filter: (the_geom_webmercator && '0103000020110F0000010000000500000000000000441519C1000000002BC5524100000000441519C1000000C069CB524100000000048E18C1000000C069CB524100000000048E18C1000000002BC5524100000000441519C1000000002BC55241'::geometry)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 798260
Planning time: 0.134 ms
Execution time: 414.343 ms
```

### PostGIS version

```
POSTGIS="2.2.2" GEOS="3.5.0-CAPI-1.9.0 r4084" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.0, released 2014/04/16" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" (core procs from "2.2.2" need upgrade) RASTER (raster procs from "2.2.2" need upgrade) – alasarr 2 mins ago
```

Comment: Don't paste screen shots of text into the question. Can you copy and paste those as code? I can't read them to help you.

Comment: Done. I think is a bit better now

Comment: I tried to backport your new query plans into that. Feel free to upgrade the plans but try to keep the style.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130856/postgis-doesnt-use-spatial-index-with-st-intersects). The && operator actually does a bounding box query, whereas, ST_Intersects uses a bounding box query to determine which geometries to test for actual comparison -- so you would expect && to be quicker. However, it is likely that the use of ST_MakeEnvelope to the right of && is making the query planner chose a full table scan for some reason (as is evident from the explain). Try creating the geometry first, in a CTE, and see if you can "fool" the optimizer.

Comment: You're right! it works inside a CTE

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This sort of finding comes up fairly often, and it is a bit obscure, so is  worth restating. If you define a geometry within a function that uses it, such as ST_Intersects or && (which ST_Intersects uses under the hood), then the query planner chooses a full table scan, as "it" has no knowledge of the outcome of the geometry creation function, ie, **ST_MakeEnvelope** in this case.. If you define the geometry you want to check for intersection in a CTE, then the optimizer is dealing with a known quantity, and will use a spatial index, if available.

So, rewritting your query as:

```
WITH test_geom (geom) AS 
   (SELECT ST_MakeEnvelope(-410961,4920492,-402305,4926887,3857))
  SELECT COUNT(*) as value
    FROM alasarr_social_mv mv, test_geom tg 
   WHERE ST_Intersects(mv.the_geom_webmercator, tg.geom)
```

will now use a spatial index. Likewise, && will now use an index to check for a bounding box, and, (while I can't test against your data), should be faster than ST_Intersects.

Interestingly, in your query, ST_Intersects is using a bitmap scan (not a gist) index, while && is using no index. So, both queries will be quicker with the CTE, but && should now be quicker than ST_Intersects.

There is more explanation of what is going on in [this question and its answers/comments](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130856/postgis-doesnt-use-spatial-index-with-st-intersects).

**EDIT**: To make this explicit, if you look at the definition of ST_Intersects in **postgis.sql** (which is called by `CREATE EXTENSION postgis` and found in the contrib directory of your Postgres install), you will see:

```
---- Inlines index magic
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_Intersects(geom1 geometry, geom2 geometry)
    RETURNS boolean
    AS 'SELECT $1 OPERATOR(&&) $2 AND _ST_Intersects($1,$2)'
    LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE ;
```

including the comment: inlines index magic.

Comment: I don't think ST_Intersects uses && under the hood.

Comment: @EvanCarroll, check my edit. Have a look at postgis.sql, where the functions are defined, and it should be clearer.